# Requesting /jwt-auth/v1/token says "The username field is empty"

Tags: wordpress, jwt

I installed and configured the [jwt-auth plugin for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) and configured it as it says in the documentation, i.e by editing the .htaccess file as it said.

It was working fine around a couple weeks ago. But now whenever I hit it, it says "The username field is empty".

Has anything changed with WordPress or jwt-auth plugin recently? Because I'm stumped on what to do next. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Also, my WordPress is 5.0.3 and jwt-auth is 1.2.5 if that's of any use.

[image: Postman Output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to send "username" and "password" in body.
e.g.

```
{
    "username": "test@test.com",
    "password": "12345678"
}
```

and in headers send only

```
"[{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json"}]"
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This worked. Can you tell me why it happened though? Thanks a ton again.

Comment: Your welcome. And actually this is happened because you are passing the fields "username" and "password" in "Headers" instead of "Body". And in "Headers" we have to sent "[{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json"}]".